# MySQL sync from another database with read only account

Tags: mysql

Supposing I have a database A, I would like to create database B on another server, that has exactly the same data as A.

How can I sync the two database, if

- I have a read only account from A.
- I can do anything on B.

Answer (score 1):

Make a script that exports the data from database A, and import into database B. Set up a cronjob that executes it however often you want the sync to occur.

If you want it to be more efficient, then track database changes in database A, and only update those to database B instead of the entire thing.

Comment: It there any solution that could be more efficient if I would like to keep two databases in sync? (i.e. the data in A will be changed and B needs to be updated.)

Comment: Please see the second part of the answer. You need to keep a change log, any updates that were made to database A lets say within 24 hours, then you push the change log to database b, and reset it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try out your suggestion in the second part.